# wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -9. error. How can I get rid of this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (qt patched) with python 3.6 and pdfkit as wrapper for wkhtmltopdf.
I am getting this error "wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -9. error:" and I am stuck not able to find any  information what this error is related to. Can someone please guide me to fix this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your wkhtmltopdf process running out of memory.

Please increase the cpu and memory of the system where you are running this process.

Comment: My system has 4cpu cores and 8gb ram. Is that not enough?